# From integer-indexed for loop enumeration to range-for

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I have some code that enumerates some data, something like this:

```
int count;
InitDataEnumeration(/* some init params */, &count);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{ 
    EnumGetData(i, &data);
    // process data ...
}
```

I'd like to convert this code in a form suitable to C++11's **range-for**.

I was thinking of defining a `DataEnumerator` wrapper class, whose constructor would call the above `InitDataEnumeration()` function.

The idea would be to use this wrapper class like this:

```
DataEnumerator enumerator{/* init params*/};

for (const auto& data : enumerator) 
{
    // process data ...
}
```

How could the former `int`-indexed for loop be refactored in the latter range-based form?

I was thinking of exposing `begin()` and `end()` methods from the enumerator wrapper class, but I don't know what kind of iterators they should return, and how to define such iterators.

Note that the iteration process is forward-only.

Comment: I don't see what kind of answer to my question is given in the "duplicate" linked question.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for can be done with [`boost::irange`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html).  It will construct a lazy range of integers in the range `[first, last)` and you can just drop it right in like you use `i` in your for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{ 
    EnumGetData(i, &data);
    // process data ...
}
```

Becomes

```
for (auto i : boost::irange(0, count))
{
    EnumGetData(i, &data);
    // process data ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't add anything good to the index for. Please see my second code snippet for what was the desired code.

Answer (score 1):

You require an input iterator this example completely copied from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator :

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <algorithm>
>
> template<long FROM, long TO>
> class Range {
> public:
>     // member typedefs provided through inheriting from std::iterator
>     class iterator: public std::iterator<
>                     std::input_iterator_tag,   // iterator_category
>                     long,                      // value_type
>                     long,                      // difference_type
>                     const long*,               // pointer
>                     long                       // reference
>                                   >{
>     long num = FROM;
>     public:
>     explicit iterator(long _num = 0) : num(_num) {}
>     iterator& operator++() {num = TO >= FROM ? num + 1: num - 1; return *this;}
>     iterator operator++(int) {iterator retval = *this; ++(*this); return retval;}
>     bool operator==(iterator other) const {return num == other.num;}
>     bool operator!=(iterator other) const {return !(*this == other);}
>     reference operator*() const {return num;}
>     };
>     iterator begin() {return iterator(FROM);}
>     iterator end() {return iterator(TO >= FROM? TO+1 : TO-1);}
> };
>
> int main() {
>     // std::find requires a input iterator
>     auto range = Range<15, 25>();
>     auto itr = std::find(range.begin(), range.end(), 18);
>     std::cout << *itr << '\n'; // 18
>
>     // Range::iterator also satisfies range-based for requirements
>     for(long l : Range<3, 5>()) {
>     std::cout << l << ' '; // 3 4 5
>     }
>     std::cout << '\n';
> }
> ```

Comment: I rolled the edit back to have quotes as this is copied material and should be marked up as such

Comment: Also note that this is a template so it only works when the size is know at compile time.  If it is run time dependent this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about `begin()` and `end()`, whatever they return should supply:

- operator++ (prefix only is enough)
- operator!=
- operator*

All pretty self-explanatory.

Notice that no traits or categories are required, as would be for iterators intended for some standard library algorithms - just bare minimum.

Answer (score -1):

`for(auto x : y)` Here, `y` must be an object of a class that has a `begin()` method and an `end()` method that each returns an object implementing the concept of an iterator. The iterator must be incrementable (`iter++`), must be able to accurately determine if it is equal to another iterator of the same kind (via `!=`) and must de-reference to whatever `x` needs to be.

This is something you should consider doing if you either A) are bored or otherwise have nothing better to do or B) have a legit need to. While this is not difficult to do, neither is it trivial.